# How do I create a loop function in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, sequence

Hi I need to create input numbers between 0 to 1 by 0.1. I named it

```
prior <- seq(0,1,0.10)
```

Now I want those numbers input in a lda function.

```
 Lda.obj <- lda(Y~., data=liver, prior=c(1-prior,prior)
```

I’m new to R and only know basics. I’m still trying to figure out how to I use loops and functions.
Later after I’m able to get those 10 numbers into the lda function I want to graph those points.

Answer (score 1):

```
prior_input <- 0
Lda.obj <- c()
for (i in 1:11) {
  Lda.obj[i] <- lda(Y~., data=liver, prior=c(1-prior_input, prior_input))
  prior_input <- prior_input + 0.1
}
```

Something like this?

Comment: I tried it and it gave me This error: error in lda.default(x, grouping,,) group means are numerically identical

Comment: ```Show in New Window
Call:
lda(V7 ~ ., data = Liver)

Prior probabilities of groups:
Not Severe     Severe 
 0.5797101  0.4202899 

Group means:
                 V1       V2      V3       V4       V5   Drinks
Not Severe 89.81500 68.34000 29.8250 25.99000 43.17000 3.392500
Severe     90.63448 71.97931 31.2069 22.78621 31.54483 3.541379

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
               LD1
V1      0.08311791
V2      0.02263406
V3      0.05892900
V4     -0.11811831
V5     -0.01497230
Drinks  0.06061389 ```

Comment: Thanks Julie! Prior had two different uses, which I hadn't noticed, so I made a change. Can you try now please?